# Настройка локального хоста на wamp

Tags: wamp

недавно перешел c OpenServer на wamp и столкнулся с настройкой локального хоста. на форумах пишут, что в файле  httpd-vhosts.conf ввести

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ishop
  ServerAlias www.ishop
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ishop"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ishop">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

не нашел правильного решения с

Answer (score 0):

В hosts файл прописывал ishop?
Попробуйте разрешить доступ всем Allow from all.
Ну и DocumentRoot  с Directory укажите полный путь: C:/wamp/www/ishop

Comment: в нижний части файла  вот так  127.0.0.1 ishop?   Allow from all  он за что отвечает?  заранее благодарен

Comment: Да, 127.0.0.1 ishop
Allow from all какие хосты могут получить доступ к области